# How to use accessibilityPath

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uibezierpath, voiceover

I have this tableViewCell with a titleLabel on the left and a textField on the right.

[image]

I disabled the accessibility of the titleLabel and give the textField an accessibilityLabel of the text of the titleLabel, to avoid duplicates.

The question is that I want to make the textFiled has a focus frame that has the same size of the tableViewCell. In other words, when the users focus the textField, I would like it to look like the focus is on the cell.

It seems I can achieve this by using accessibilityPath. I tried this but it is not working.

```
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.frame)

cell.textField.accessibilityPath = path
```

Any idea how to use the accessibilityPath? Thanks!

Comment: where r u trying to do this ? in cell for row at index method ?

Comment: if you only want to highlight the table cell, then y dont u do it directly by making the table cell as accessible element but not its subviews ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Yeah it's in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.
If I make the cell accessible then it will lose the traits of textField. Like when you focus the cell, it will not accounce "textField, double tap to edit" etc..

Answer (score 0):

The cell's path should be in it's superview's reference frame (the `tableView`). You may need to convert the cell path into the `textField`'s superview coordinates. Try something like:

`let accessibilityPath = cell.convertRect(path, toView: cell.textField)`

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that I need to convert the frame to screen coordinates! I just realized that I can use accessibilityFrame and use UIAccessibilityConvertFrameToScreenCoordinates to help convert the frame. This works fine for the first few cells but once you scroll the table, all frames are screwed up :(

Comment: Take a look at this. Seems someone's solved it. https://coderwall.com/p/sswchq/ios-custom-views-and-accessibility-in-table-views
Another approach would be to make a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass that handles the tap and editing so Accessibility would select the whole cell.